# Order /tracks by Like Count

Tags: soundcloud

Is it possible in using the Soundcloud Javascript API to order results by like count? Everything I can find says you can no longer order by 'hotness' but nothing about other sorts. I've tried adding an `order` parameter to my API call such as:

```
SC.get('/tracks', {
    limit: 200,
    genres: 'electronic',
    order: 'likes_count'
}).then(function(tracks) {
    console.log(tracks);
});
```

But the API call returns a 400 Bad Request, as soon as I remove the `order: 'likes_count'` line the API call works again.

Answer (score 0):

The [order parameter](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/removing-hotness-param) is no longer in the SoundCloud API.